# Как перевести javascript массив в php массив?

Tags: javascript, php, массивы

У меня php с помощью `echo` выводит javascript, а в этом джаваскрипте я создаю пустой массив: `var deck = []`, а потом добавляю в него элементы функцией `push()`
И мне нужно получить этот массив в php, чтобы потом записать данные из массива в файл на сервере, так как javascript выполняется на компьютере клиента, я этого из джаваскрипта сделать не могу.

Массив самый простой, одномерный.

Comment: Передать массив с помощью Ajax?

Comment: Я в аджаксе не разбираюсь. Покажите как это сделать на примере если не сложно

Answer (score 1):

Отправить данный массив AJAX'ом на обработку php скрипту. 
Как вы понимаете, php выполняется на сервере, а js на клиенте. Поэтому при генерации страницы, такое реализовать не получится (если этот массив заполняется клиентом).

Comment: У меня нет задачи это сделать на текущей странице, а передавать массив AJAX'ом я не умею, можете показать на примере?

Comment: `$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'путь до вашего обработчика php',
 data: { ArrayToPhp: your_array },
 success: function(data) {        
console.log(data);
     }});`

Только это надо повесить на обработчик, какой-нибудь. После каких действий, вы хотите отправлять данные?

Comment: Понял, но что писать в обработчике?

Comment: Получаете ваш массив
`$ArrayFromAjax = $_POST['ArrayToPhp'];`
Теперь у вас есть ваш массив в виде переменной в вашем обработчике

Comment: У меня создана форма и после того, как человек нажимает отправить должен отправиться массив в php для записи в файл. Но у меня очень нестандартная форма и напрямую её не отправить.

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спасибо)

Comment: Значит на форму вешаете отмену стандартного действия, а сами выполняете вашу функцию - отправки всех данных на php обработчик:
`$( "form" ).submit(function() {
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'путь до вашего обработчика php', data: { ArrayToPhp: your_array }, success: function(data) { console.log(data); }});
});`

Comment: Сделал всё по вашей инструкции, но вот какая петушка: когда я создаю новый php файл - обработчик, его блокирует wordpress потому что нету подписи что это плагин и соответственно ajax не отправляется. А если новый плагин делать, что он пытается принять ajax до того, как он отправился. Как мне сказать вордпрессу, что этот php файл относится к моему плагину?

Comment: Вы сделали именно через `$( "form" ).submit(function() {...})` ?

Comment: Нет, так как у меня всю информацию через формы не отправить. Мне именно нужно массив отправить из джаваскрипта и принять его в пхп.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно понять, на какой элемент вешать событие отправки данных. И использовать его для инициализации ajax

Comment: Решил вопрос отправкой массива в json формате через ajax. Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: @ZeroBone Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/80180)